# Script enters all conditionals

Tags: bash, shell

I'd like to write a script that takes 2 parameters,

- The first is parameter that could be "alpha/beta/tcp_friendliness/fast_convergence".
- The Second should be a number for the alpha/beta cases and a 0/1 for the other 2.

for example: `./manage_cc alpha 512`

Now i've wrote the following script that supposedly covers my cases, but it seems to go into all the conditionals. surely my syntax is broken so any help would be appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash


echo -n $2 > /sys/module/tcp_tuner/parameters/$1

if [["$1" == ""] || ["$2" == ""]]
then
        echo "You need to pass a property to modify as a first parameter and a value as the second"
fi

if  [["$1" == "alpha"] || ["$1" == "beta"]]
then
        echo -n $2 > /sys/module/tcp_tuner/parameters/$1
else
        if [["$1" == "tcp_friendliness"] || ["$1" == "fast_convergence"]]
        then
                if [["$2" != "0"] && ["$2" != "1"]]
                then
                        echo "This parameter only accepts a boolean value (0/1)"
                        exit 1
                else
                        echo -n $2 > /sys/module/tcp_tuner/parameters/$1
                fi
        else
                echo "The only accepted values for first parameter are alpha/beta/tcp_friendliness/fast_convergence"
                exit 1
        fi
fi
```

Comment: Paste your entire script at https://shellcheck.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition syntax is wrong. When you start a condition with `[[` you have to end it with `]]`, not just `]`. They don't nest like parentheses.

```
if  [[ "$1" == "alpha" || "$1" == "beta" ]]
```

Comment: @Omar, the keywords `[[` and `]]` act like any other commands: they need to separated from their arguments with whitespace. They are not mere syntax.

Answer (score 3):

A rewrite of your code:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

write() {
    printf "%s" "$2" > "/sys/module/tcp_tuner/parameters/$1"
}

die() {
    echo "$*" >&2
    exit 1
}

main() {
    [[ -z $2 ]] && die "You need to pass a property to modify as a first parameter and a value as the second"

    case $1 in
        alpha|beta)
            write "$1" "$2"
            ;;
        tcp_friendliness|fast_convergence)
            if [[ "$2" == "0" || "$2" == "1" ]]; then
                write "$1" "$2"
            else
                die "This parameter only accepts a boolean value (0/1)"
            fi
            ;;
        *)  die "The only accepted values for first parameter are alpha/beta/tcp_friendliness/fast_convergence"
            ;;
    esac
}

main "$@"
```